Cost-Effective Methods for Fine-Tuning LLMs with RAFT
I'm new to LLMs and fine-tuning in general so please bear with me if I've made obvious mistakes!
I have no GPU/cloud based platform other than a free tral GCP account.
I'm trying to fine-tune an LLM using the RAFT method (Retrieval Augmented Fine-Tuning). The goal is to enhance the mode's ability to answer questions like an 'open-book' exam. Here is the RAFT paper:https://arxiv.org/html/2403.10131v1 and the corresponding github repo: https://github.com/ShishirPatil/gorilla
Here's what I've done so far:

I've followed the RAFT instructions and generated a JSON file using a pdf input (BMW 3 Series wiki page).
I put credit in my Open AI account and used their API to generate the JSONL
I modified the keys in the jsonl file to meet the requirements for GCP Vertex AI.
I uploaded the jsonl file to vertex ai to fine tune the 'text-bison@002' model, keeping the default parameters.

The fine tuning ran fine, but when testing the model it failed to answer questions based on the content of the PDF. I also cannot export the fine-tuned model (which my aim is to do, specifically in gguf format), which i guess are due to the limitations of using the free account. In the RAFT paper, they recommend continuing the fine-tuning on Azure AI Studio with Llama-2-7b, but this also requires a paid account.
Given the constraints that I don't have a GPU, am on a tight budget, and I am looking for that most cost-effective way to fine-tune with RAFT, ideally using open-source models like llmama;
My question is:
What is your recommendation for the cheapest, yet reliable way to fine-tune LLMs without access to expensive hardware or platforms? Are there any alternative approaches or platforms you would suggest?
Any advice or tips would be greatly appreciated!
I have done the steps for RAFT and tried to fine-tune using only CPU but of course that just crashed everything. So I signed up for GCP Free trial to make use of the free trial credits they provided, but cannot seem to go further and am not sure how to continue.
